# Is there a 4e ritual or effect similar to Silence in 3.5 and 5e?

Tags: spells, dnd-4e, magic-items, rituals

Silence in 4e is a ritual and described as a "ward against eavesdropping" that stops noise from escaping an area, whereas the other versions stop noise from being produced and can be used to stop spells with verbal components.

I want to make a 4e item with the latter kind of effect — **stopping noise from being produced entirely** — but before I reinvent the wheel, is there an effect like D&D 3.5e or 5e's Silence in 4e under a different name?

Comment: D&D 4e doesn't have a mechanical concept of verbal components, so there isn't going to be a "no casting spells with verbal components" effect in the game. Do you just want to muffle/silence an area? Stop powers from functioning? Something else?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I'm still getting re-acclimated to 4e, and I forgot components aren't a thing. I mainly want the muffling of an area.

This is for a magical gavel, so the choice of powers is largely a flavor thing. It's supposed to be able to use thunderwave, silence, and zone of truth (which it seems is also missing), like something that would actually be used in a courtroom in a high magic setting.

Answer (score 1):

Effects in 4e tend to be very mechanical. There isn't really anything that says explicitly that it prevents sound, not even (as you noted) the Silence ritual (Player's Handbook, page 312) which "only" provides a penalty to Perception checks to Listen to something inside the warded area from outside.

If you want something that will silence an area entirely, you will probably need to invent your own ritual spell that does so.